# Emphasis on a feature while training a vanilla nn

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, hyperparameters

I have some 360 odd features on which I am training my neural network model.
The accuracy I am getting is abysmally bad. There is one feature amongst the 360 that is more important than the others.

Right now, it does not enjoy any special status amongst the other features.
Is there a way to lay emphasis on one of the features while training the model? I believe this could improve my model's accuracy.

I am using Python 3.5 with Keras and Scikit-learn.

EDIT: I am attempting a regression problem

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would make sure that this feature alone has a decent prediction probability, but I am assuming that you already made sure of it.

Then, one approach that you could take, is to "embed" your 359 other features in a first layer, and only feed in your special feature once you have compressed the remaining information.

Contrary to what most tutorials make you believe, you do not have to add in all features already in the first layer, but can technically insert them at any point in time (or even multiple times).

The first layer that captures your other inputs is then some form of "PCA approximator", where you are embedding a high-dimensional feature space (359 dimensions) into something that is less dominant over your other feature (maybe 20-50 dimensions as a starting point?)

Of course there is no guarantee that this will work, but you might have a much better chance of getting attention on your special feature, although I am fairly certain that in general you should still see an increase in performance if the single feature is strongly enough correlated with your output.

The other question that is still open is the kind of task you are training for, i.e., whether you are doing some form of classification (if so, how many classes?), or regression. This might also influence architectural choices, and the amount of focus you can/should put on a single feature.

Answer (score 0):

There are several feature selection and importance techniques in machine learning. Please follow this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-selection-techniques-in-machine-learning-with-python-f24e7da3f36e).

Comment: I did visit the link. However I did not find a way to tweak the 'importance' given to a feature. Do let me know if i missed anything.